# Download file from SharePoint 2013 with authentication

Tags: .net, vb.net, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007

I have a vb.net Tool, that Downloads a ***. Zip** file from a SharePoint Server. Till now it worked under **SharePoint 2007**.
Under **SharePoint 2013** and I’m not abel to Download the File anymore. Under SharePoint 2013 the User has to Authenticate himself over this mask Authentication side in the Browser.

[image]

This was the Old Solution that worked on SharePoint 2007

```
Dim WebIntranet As New WebClient
Dim strURL as String = "https://example.com/content/P123456/Documents/File.zip"

WebIntranet.UseDefaultCredentials = True
'Download the File from the Server
 WebIntranet.DownloadFile(strURL,
     "D:\Temp\File.zip ")
```

For the new Solution it didn’t work and i tryed a few things:
First Approch:

```
Dim client As New WebClient 
Dim _UserAgend As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"
Dim strURL as String = "https://example.com/content/P123456/Documents/File.zip"

client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, _UserAgend)

WebIntranet.DownloadFile(strURL,
     "D:\Temp\File.zip ")
```

Second Approch:

```
Dim securedPassword As SecureString = New SecureString
Dim _UserAgend As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"
Dim username As String = "TestUser@Test.com"
Dim password As String = "123456"
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, _UserAgend)


For Each c In password.ToCharArray()
    securedPassword.AppendChar(c)
Next
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, _UserAgend)
client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, securedPassword) WebIntranet.DownloadFile(strURL,
     "D:\Temp\File.zip ")
```

Both of the Approches didn’t work, they did not Donwloaded the File from the Sharepoint.
**They only Downloaded the Authenticaton side and named it "File.zip"**
Any help is welcomed

---

Raw Request from the Download

[image]

Comment: Inspect the raw request first to see what responses you get. While yes we know authentication is needed. The raw responses should give low level clues as to what is needed.

Comment: @Nkosi ok, will do that. How do i get the Raw Request?

Comment: You can use something like Fiddler to view the traffic when making the request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if it works for your authentication method, but I could download a file like this (set reference to *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client* and *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime*):

```
Imports System.Security
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

...
Dim securePwd As SecureString
Dim credentials As SharePointOnlineCredentials
Dim list As List
Dim listItem As ListItem
Dim listItemFile As File
Dim fileRef As String
Dim fileInfo As FileInformation
Dim fileName As String

...
credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePwd)

Using context As ClientContext = New ClientContext(BASE_URL)
    context.Credentials = credentials

    list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(LIST_TITLE)
    listItem = list.GetItemById(ITEM_ID)
    listItemFile = listItem.File

    context.Load(list)
    context.Load(listItem, Function(x As ListItem) x.File)
    context.Load(listItemFile, Function(x As File) x.ServerRelativeUrl)
    context.ExecuteQuery()

    fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl
    fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef)
    fileName = IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, listItem.File.Name)

    Using stream As IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName)
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(stream)
    End Using
End Using
```

`BASE_URL`, `LIST_TITLE` and `ITEM_ID` I got from the URL when browsing the file-to-download in the browser.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thakns, i will give it a try next morning

Comment: I'm not sure, from where you got the LIST_TITLE and ITEM_ID

Comment: I logged in on the Sharepoint site and navigated to the list, where I can download the file. The address in the browser address bar contained the LIST_TITLE just infront of the "Forms.AllItems" part. My address bar showed: https://<company>.sharepoint.com/sites/global/epd/ce/de/Department Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?... so my list title was "Department Documents". Then I hovered with the mouse over the file link. The browser shows the URL in the lower left corner. It contained a part like "...&ListItemID=1234&...", so my ITEM_ID was 1234.

Comment: On context.ExecuteQuery() he throws this Exception. "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

Comment: Then either you used the wrong LIST_TITLE and/or ITEM_ID or my way doesn't work with your required authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. Don't forget to replace site details and credentials

```
    Using context As ClientContext = New ClientContext("https://example.com")
        context.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("TestUser@Test.com", "123456")
        Dim file As File = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/content/P123456/Documents/File.zip")
        Dim filestrem As ClientResult(Of IO.Stream) = file.OpenBinaryStream()
        context.Load(file)
        context.ExecuteQuery()
        Using stream As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream()
            filestrem.Value.CopyTo(stream)
            IO.File.WriteAllBytes("D:\Temp\" + file.Name, stream.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: On context.ExecuteQuery() he throws this Exception. "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

Comment: Can you try `testuser` instead `testuser@test.com`?